# Plotly in R changes x-axis starting from 1970

Tags: r, plotly

I have a dataframe with timestamp column and one integer column with range 0-8.
I'd like to plot a marker for every data point, but plotly shows me a plot with x-axis starting in 1970.
When I convert integer column to factor, x-axis range is set correctly.
Any idea, how to set marker color using integer column and get proper range for x-axis?
Bad range:

```
library(plotly)
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)

set.seed(99)
tsRange = seq(ymd_hm("2021-01-01 00:00", tz = "CET"), ymd_hm("2021-01-08 23:59", tz = "CET"), by = "60 secs")
nRows <- 20
df <- tibble(
  ts = sample(tsRange, nRows),
  point = sample(1:8, nRows, replace = TRUE)
) %>% 
  mutate(point_fac = as.factor(point))
plot_ly(df, x = ~ts, y = "something", color = ~point) %>% add_markers()
```

good range

```
plot_ly(df, x = ~ts, y = "something", color = ~point_fac) %>% add_markers()
```

Regards
Paweł

Comment: The time is probably in UNIX format, which is milliseconds since 1970-1-1.

Comment: Is that related to [this github issue](https://github.com/ropensci/plotly/issues/1653)?

Comment: @Ben yes, it looks like my issue! Thank you very much. If you write an naswer, I will be very glad to accept it :-)

Comment: I have the same issue when I try to use animated chart  in plotly

Comment: Setting my date column to character worked for me: